# How can I transfer photo's from my Kodak camera that normally would use KODAK EASYSHARE Software?

Tags: drivers, camera

Normally I would plug my camera into my Windows XP pc, and the software would auto start, and transfer the files to a set location.

I need to be able to perform the same or similar function on my PC installed with Ubuntu 10.04 (LTS). I would like to plug the camera in (USB), and then be able to select the files I want. At the moment, the camera does not seem to recognise the PC. I do not want to rely on the Windows PC anymore.

Comment: Which Kodak camera do you have?

Comment: Don't F-spot or Shotwell do that? , also i'd guess that when you connect your camera Nautilus doesn't prompt you to do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use rapid-photo-downloader for my canon and nikon cameras. I think it supports kodak too.

[photographic workflow](http://damonlynch.net/rapid/index.html)

Comment: and @ Uri : I have tried all the suggestions mentioned above. It looks like Kodak requires you to use a Windows based system. I have even tried creating a Kodac account, and installing the app for Firefox, but still unable to locate the folder the contains the images on the camera. Instead, I am only able to locate a folder that would, in windows, install the Kodak software. Seems I am stuck. Any other suggestions out there?